# javascript filter with complex condition in accolades

Tags: javascript, filter

Why does this work:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(
  word => word.length > 6
);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

but after modifying this piece, doesn't:

```
const result = words.filter(
      word => {
        word.length > 6
      }
    );
```

Notice that I want to place  `word.length > 6` inside accolades where I want to actually have more complex intermediate calculations (more than 1 line).

Any advice please thanks.

Comment: You need to add `return` keyword

Comment: on your working example you use one line syntax in which you can remove brackets and the return statement

Comment: [your code comes from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First version:

```js
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
    const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
    console.log(result)
```

Second Version

```js
    var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
        const result = words.filter(word => {return word.length > 6});
        console.log(result)
```

Use first version when you have a single line expression while using second version while you have more complex condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `return` keyword when your expression is surrounded by brackets:

```
const result = words.filter(
  word => {
    return word.length > 6
  }
);
```